# Clear spam folder from Gmail app

Tags: gmail

I have an LG-38 from Straight Talk. I have over 1000 spam messages in my Gmail account.

How can I erase all of my spam messages at one time?

Comment: I am on my Mobile LG 38 Android I can't find a button that will erase all Spam messages at one time

Comment: Would it not be easier deleting them all from the web interface instead? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6602?hl=en I find that to be more quicker and simpler. If you have a PC nearby, simply log into your gmail account and follow steps in link above

Answer (score 2):

I am on a MotoX Pure, but the Gmail application should be the same or at least very similar.

1. Open Gmail
2. Navigate to your Spam folder
3. Tap on the icon in the far upper-right corner that looks like three dots sitting on top one another
4. A dropdown will appear and the only option should be to "Empty Spam"